# How do I desing my application on Java(eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new with learning Java. I was learning C# and C# has own designer inside it. Like **" Add: Button, Label, Timer, TextBox"** But in Eclipse there is no such a thing. Should I use and external program for design or I'm blind and can't see it?

Comment: Are you using Swing or JavaFx?

Comment: I personally use JavaFX for java application design. It is simple to understand more it uses the framework CSS of the web. [jfoenix](http://www.jfoenix.com/)

Comment: firstly we need to know what framework will use: JavaFX, Swing, Vadin... some of this frameworks have a plugin for Eclipse

Comment: Thanks all of you I found solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Eclipse RCP, that is a good documented environment to create graphical GUI's
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Rich_Client_Platform/FAQ

Comment: Thanks I will look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NetBeans it has all of the features you are looking for (Add: Button, Label, Timer, TextBox), And it supports java. It is very easy to use and it is very similar to eclipse. good luck!